# How to put some elements above a blurr filter / css effect?

Tags: html, css

We are using a blurr filter in css to hide content on our site from a visitor.

We do that with

```
#myDiv{        
display:block;
        -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
        -moz-filter: blur(15px);
        -o-filter: blur(15px);
        -ms-filter: blur(15px);
        filter: blur(15px);
        opacity: 0.95;
}
```

in the basic structure of

```
<html>
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="Element1">
        <div id="ShouldBeVisible">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can we make onyl element "ShouldBeVisible" be displayed over the filter? The background of the text should still be the blurr effect.

We are currently considering using a picture and playing with the z-axis, but we are hoping for a more elegant solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: put it outside the blur div and `position:absolute` it to where you want.

Comment: First of all, your id value is invalud

Comment: @Andrew That would be nice, however this is a much simplified version of the problem. We have global css for fonts etc that are applied to the content container. Also it has some issues since our content is dynamically generated